# Where and how to install waagent (Linux VM Agent) via CLI?

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, command-line-interface, python

I am creating a VM from disk in azure from CLI.
The VM gets created successfully, but in the properties, it shows **VM agent unavailable**. Because of which I am unable to ssh to the VM.
I am creating VM using the following command :

```
az vm create --resource-group RESOURCE-GRP-NAME --location eastus --name VM-NAME --os-type linux --attach-os-disk DISK-NAME
```

As I am using [--attach-os-disk] option, it does not allow me to give user name and password. So I have to install this waaagent. 
But **where exactly this agents needs to be installed and how?** I am doing this from *CLI*, so answer via *CLI* would be better.

Comment: Answered on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914627/how-to-install-the-azure-linux-agent-waagent-via-cli-on-a-vm/48935203#48935203

Comment: In fact, this is not possible. You need prepare your VHD in your local Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon operating system, the commands vary a little. Below is the link for the MSFT Documentation on how to install / update the Azure VM agent on Linux.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/update-agent